# Detect what data is (not yet) received by client on TCP stream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, stream

I have a server that produces data, and the client receives this data. Only the server is too fast, and overloads the client. Eventually, the server will block on his send operations.

Now, I'm not really interested in old data from the server, rather, the server could skip a few messages and only send what's really important to the client.

On the client, I can use `Client.Available` to find out how much data is left in the stream, but I cannot figure out how to get this number on the server/sender. I can change the `SendBufferSize`, but rather I would know how much space is free in the SendBuffer and react to that accordantly.

I could let the client report how far he's lagging behind, but that feels like reinventing the TCP protocol at application level. Also, I do not trust a already slow client to warn my server in time.

Is there any way to read the TCP used/unused window size or send buffer?

Comment: _"I'm not really interested in old data from the server, rather, the server could skip a few messages"_ - use UDP.

Comment: Eeeh, no, all data the server does send should arrive, I said I could skip messages, not skip packets.

Comment: That does not compute. A message can span one or more packets, so if you can skip messages, you can skip packets. TCP is a stream that you can't skip, so if you must be able to skip, you can't use TCP.

Comment: A packet can also span one or more messages, also, it is not safe to discard half a message if a message spans multiple packets, not to mention I do not want to reorder my packets manually on the client when they arrive out of order. TCP does all this for me, and that is good.

Comment: "I don't want to" isn't really an answer to "You must". Using TCP, you have to consume all packets in-order, but if you want to do so in realtime, you must consume faster, which you can't. You can however create another "ack" layer; let the client tell the server it has received a message, and if the server determines the client is lagging, let the server skip sending messages.

Comment: Yeah, in theory I could just read the ack packets, but it looks like I cant access those in practice. So I probably let the client send a confirmation when it received and processed a message, effectively adding my own ack layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Eventually, the server will block on his send operations"

Frankly, the above is the real bug here. There's no reason a server should block just because some client isn't receiving data fast enough. The server should be using non-blocking, asynchronous I/O and should otherwise continue to work normally, even if a client isn't reading fast enough.

Now, even if you address the blocking issue, you may also have the issue of the client receiving data not quickly enough. I.e. as you mentioned, you want the client to not receive data it can't process. You have at least a few choices here:

- Require the client to actively response to a processed message before sending another one.

**Pro:** this is an immediate solution, in the sense that the server will never exceed the transmission rate that the client can handle.
**Con:** this would add bandwidth overhead and latency to your network protocol. A client with a high ping time will suffer, even if it's otherwise able to receive data quickly.

- Keep track of the data rate the client appears to be able to handle, and slow the materialization of messages so that the server does not exceed this rate.

**Pro:** this solution will at all times maintain a transmission rate as high as the client is capable of dealing with.
**Con:** at least initially, and perhaps intermittently as the client's own capacity varies, this may exceed temporarily the client's ability to keep up

- Use UDP, which will allow the network transport layer to discard datagrams that the client isn't processing quickly enough.

**Pro:** this solution delegates the whole problem to the network transport layer, leaving you to worry about the real details of your server and client
**Con:** UDP is inherently unreliable. In addition to dealing with dropped datagrams (which in your case is a benefit), you also must be prepared to handle datagrams received out of order, and individual datagrams received more than once.

That's about as specific an answer as is possible, given the broadly stated question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `TcpClient.SendTimeout` to a reasonable value. If the client does not accept and consume a message before the timeout expires, the `Write` method (and its overloads) will throw a `SocketException`. You should write a catch-block that then decides whether to retry the operation or to discard the message.

Comment: I have considered this, but how do I know if my stream is still in a safe state? It could have send half the previous message before it threw the exception.

Comment: Your client should consume an entire message in one go, so that it either accepts all of the bytes or none of the bytes for each message.

Comment: You are right about the stream becoming unusable when more than 0 bytes have been written before reaching a timeout. This is a client-side error that you can detect, but cannot recover from on the server-side. You should always close the connection when this happens.

Comment: Yup, sadly. I probably end up sacrificing a thread in wait state, or wrap it in a async call somehow. It surprises me that you cant access the remaining window size, I'll keep looking for something. Thanks for thinking with me anyway.

Comment: You could keep count of the number of bytes written, and explicitly call `Stream.Flush()` to clear the outgoing buffer at key intervals (e.g. between every message). The number of bytes written should then directly correspond to the number of bytes available to the client.

Comment: Getting the number of **unread** bytes is a different story though.

Comment: What is the issue with the timeout approach anyway? No matter what angle you try to approach this problem from, your server will have to wait until the client catches up before it can send more data.

Comment: I want to send different data to different clients based on how well there connection performs. Right now I can put 10.000 messages in my socket before it blocks, even when the client has only processed a handful of them, taking minutes to catch up. I rather have the server react when there are, say, 100 messages in flight and delay the rest.

Comment: A timeout on a `Socket` renders the `Socket` unusable from that point forward. It's not a suitable solution if the intent is to simply wait for the client to catch up.