# TCP connection for real time

Tags: sockets, tcp

I want to use a real time TCP connection, I have a streaming of data from server , and I receive it by a client, but this client is too slow to receive as fast as the sender is, so  the server buffer the data until it's reach the destination, for example if I "produce" data at time t, and suppose that the client are 10 time slower, then the data produced at time t, will arrive at time 10t.

I want to make the server "drop" the data that can't  reach the client at the present time, and send the new data which is expected to arrive at the time?

B.S : I know that UDP protocol do this, but I want to do this by TCP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect what data is (not yet) received by client on TCP stream in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108223/detect-what-data-is-not-yet-received-by-client-on-tcp-stream-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @CodeCaster, so there is no way except to deal with udp? but the problem is the server use TCP connection, he give is me no choise

Comment: There are various approaches, see [proposed dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108223/detect-what-data-is-not-yet-received-by-client-on-tcp-stream-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @CodeCaster, I think to make a middle client, which receives the data from the server and resend the data by UDP to the original client, this will satisfy  what I want, right?

Comment: That's possible, if that client can receive fast enough.

Comment: @CodeCaster,  Is there any function in c Language which receive a certain number (i.e 20) of `uint16` at a time from TCP connection ?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this sort of thing in the past, and got reasonably good results.  Here's how I did it:

1) On the sending side, use setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF) to make the server's TCP socket's send buffer as small as you can get away with (since you can't drop data once it's already in the socket's send buffer, you want to keep as little data there as possible)

2) On the sending side, never proactively send() any outgoing data into the socket at all.  Instead, write a function (we'll call it DumpCurrentStateToBuffer()) that writes the "current state" bytes (that you want to send to the client) into an in-memory buffer.

3) When the client's socket select()'s (or poll()'s, or whatever mechanism you use) as ready-for-write, call DumpCurrentStateToBuffer() to create a memory-buffer of bytes that are to be sent to the client.  Now send that data to the client (if you're using blocking I/O you can do it synchronously, at the cost of potentially stalling your server until the data can be sent; OTOH if you're using non-blocking I/O, you may need to keep the memory-buffer and your current sent-bytes index into the buffer around as state variables, so you can keep sending more sub-chunks of the memory buffer over time, whenever the socket indicates that it can receive more bytes)

4) Once the memory-buffer's contents have been fully sent, you can free the memory buffer, and then wait for the socket to select as ready-for-write again; when it does, goto (3).

This technique doesn't solve all of TCP's non-real-time issues; for example, a dropped TCP packet will still have to be resent to the client.  What it does do is guarantee that the client-to-server data backlog will never be more than one or two "states" long, because you never generate any new data unless/until there is at least some room in the socket's output buffer.